# No <database> tag in the model database

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

hello ,
I probably did something to my environment because when I run my GAZEBO now I get this:

**Error [ModelDatabase.cc:228] No  tag in the model database database.config found here[http://gazebosim.org/models/]**

**Error [ModelDatabase.cc:287] Unable to download model manifests**

I'm using GAZEBO 2.2 and ROS Indigo on UBUNTU 14.04

thanks for helping...

Ron.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13234/no-%3Cdatabase%3E-tag-in-the-model-database/) by [benshaul](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/294/benshaul/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Looks like the model database server went down. Can you try again?

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2016-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [benshaul](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/294/benshaul/) on 2016-05-09**:
Tanks Nate, its working now.
How can I check it next time or restart this server manually?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2016-05-10**:
The fix requires us (OSRF) to reset a server that Gazebo relies upon. If you notice this again, please contact us and we'll resolve the issue. A longer term, and more reliable, solution is in the works.

**Comment by [Savio](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2496/savio/) on 2016-07-07**:
Hey I am having the same problem as 'benshaul'. The server that Gazebo relies on seems to be down again. In insert tab all I see is ' Connecting to model database...'

**Comment by [neuronet](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2728/neuronet/) on 2016-08-08**:
Bam got hit just now with this. Maybe we should start a contribution system..if you contribute you get the good server. :)

**Comment by [lgritters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3789/lgritters/) on 2017-09-06**:
hey, I am experiencing this problem on my computer, how can i resolve this? Im using Ubuntu 16.04

**Comment by [Abduoit](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4035/abduoit/) on 2017-10-31**:
did u guys solve it?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-10-31**:
This happens whenever the servers are down. They should be back up.

**Comment by [kayuchang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4487/kayuchang/) on 2018-01-24**:
I am having the same problem using Ubuntu 14.04, how can I solve this?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-01-25**:
The server doesn't seem to be down: http://models.gazebosim.org/

**Comment by [mero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/23421/mero/) on 2020-02-12**:
I am having the same problem now. Gazebo 7 and Ubuntu 16.04